# How com.google.cloud.tools appengine-gradle-plugin run on java17, Gralde7.5

Tags: gradle, java-17, appengine-gradle-plugin

I'm trying to use appengine-gradle-plugin with java17 and Gradle7.5.1, but I get an error and it stops.

tried:
build.gradle is:

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.cloud.tools'
```

error is:

```
Plugin with id 'com.google.cloud.tools' not found.
```

tried this too:
build.gradle is:

```
plugins {
  id("com.google.cloud.tools.appengine") version "2.8.0" apply false
}
```

error is:

```
Plugin Repositories (could not resolve plugin artifact 'com.google.cloud.tools.appengine:com.google.cloud.tools.appengine.gradle.plugin:2.8.0')
  Searched in the following repositories:
    Gradle Central Plugin Repository
```

This article states that it is "compatible with java17 and gradle 7." How should I set it up to work?

article:
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-plugins/issues/1002#issuecomment-1145183129

I expected appengine-gradle-plugin would be successfully loaded and available for the program.